# Create a dynamic variable that performs a logical test on a vector and returns a vector

Tags: r, excel

I am trying to create a variable that will check the first five elements of the vector x and return a vector of ones and zeros. ones if the variable equals X[i] and zero if not.

Something similar to =((X1:$X5=X1)*1) in excel

```
X <- c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H")
#i tried this but i had errors
T <- length(X)
vec <- rep(0,T)
for(i in 1:T){
  j <- 5
if(T-i<=j){
  j <- T-i}
else{j <- 5}

if(X[i] == X[i:(i+j)]){
  vec[i] <- 1}
  else{
    vec[i] <- 0
}
}
```

Comment: Hi Nattis. Please check my update. This will check whether elements 1:5 are equal to element 1, 2:6 are equal to element 2, 3:7 equal to element 3 etc

Comment: Thank you. This what i need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use `rollapply`

```
library(zoo)
h <- 5
+(rollapply(X, width = h + 1, FUN = function(x) x[1] == x))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#[1,]    1    1    0    0    1    0
#[2,]    1    0    0    1    0    0
#[3,]    1    0    0    1    0    0
#[4,]    1    0    0    1    0    1
#[5,]    1    0    0    0    0    1
```

---

Or using `embed` from `base R`

```
m1 <- embed(c(X, X), h + 1)[1:h, (h+1):1]
+(m1 == m1[,1])
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#[1,]    1    1    0    0    1    0
#[2,]    1    0    0    1    0    0
#[3,]    1    0    0    1    0    0
#[4,]    1    0    0    1    0    1
#[5,]    1    0    0    0    0    1
```

Comment: I want it such that X[i] == X[i:(i+h)]. each X[i] is a vector of length h

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are looking for

```r
(X[1:5] == X[1]) * 1
#> [1] 1 0 0 0 0
```

For example:

```r
X <- c("A", "B", "A", "D", "A")
(X[1:5] == X[1]) * 1
#> [1] 1 0 1 0 1
```

---

**EDIT**

For a list of vectors matching the criteria you could do:

```r
X <- c("A", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "E", "C", "A")

h <- 5

lapply(seq(length(X) - 5), function(i) (X[i:(i + h)] == X[i]) * 1)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 1 1 0 0 1 0
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 1 0 0 1 0 0
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 1 0 0 1 0 0
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] 1 0 0 1 0 1
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> [1] 1 0 0 0 0 1
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>